# SQL between date range returning a wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL query to get rows between a date range format: mm/dd/yyyy

I used the `between` operator but the result shows out of the range dates

```
Select Internship_StartDate1
From [Media_BPM].[dbo].[BP_UGME]
Where TrainingType = 'Medical Internship Training'
  and Internship_StartDate1 Between '01/%/2020%'  AND '06/%/2020%'
Order By Internship_StartDate1 desc
```

The expected result : dates of year 2020 only

The actual result is:

```
Internship_StartDate1
05/16/2018
05/06/2018
05/05/2019
05/05/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/02/2019
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2020
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2019
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2018
05/01/2017
04/30/2018
04/29/2018
04/18/2018
04/14/2017
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2020
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2019
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2018
04/01/2017
04/01/2017
04/01/2017
04/01/2017
03/19/2019
03/18/2018
03/04/2018
03/03/2019
03/03/2019
03/03/2019
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2020
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2019
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2018
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
03/01/2017
02/05/2017
02/03/2019
02/03/2019
02/03/2019
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2020
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2019
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2018
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
01/20/2019
01/19/2019
01/19/2019
01/13/2019
01/12/2019
01/12/2019
01/12/2019
01/10/2019
01/10/2019
01/10/2018
01/09/2019
01/09/2019
01/09/2017
01/08/2018
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2020
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2018
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
01/01/2009
```

Comment: Between '01/%/2020%'  AND '06/%/2020%' will not work as 'between - and' statement expects a datatype date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you use SQL Server.
Maybe you think that `%` is a wildcard char in this condition denoting any char, but this is not the case.
You can use `%` with the operator `LIKE` but not with `BETWEEN`.
Use the function [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Select Internship_StartDate1 
from [Media_BPM].[dbo].[BP_UGME] 
where TrainingType = 'Medical Internship Training' 
AND FORMAT(Internship_StartDate1, 'yyyyMM') Between '202001' AND '202006' 
Order By Internship_StartDate1 desc
```

Comment: thx for the answer,, I see but when i use format() i'm getting this error "Argument data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for argument 1 of format function.
"

Comment: What is the data type of Internship_StartDate1? Also do you use SQL Server?

Comment: yes using SQL Server 2014 Management ,, data type of Internship_StartDate1 is nvarchar

Comment: Then change `FORMAT(Internship_StartDate1, 'yyyyMM')`  to `FORMAT(convert(date, Internship_StartDate1, 101), 'yyyyMM')`

Comment: Or instead of `FORMAT(Internship_StartDate1, 'yyyyMM')` write `RIGHT(Internship_StartDate1, 4) + LEFT(Internship_StartDate1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

just set the format of datetime

```
 SELECT Internship_StartDate1 from [Media_BPM].[dbo].[BP_UGME]
 WHERE TrainingType = 'Medical Internship Training'
 AND YEAR(CONVERT(date, Internship_StartDate1,103)) BETWEEN '2019' AND '2020'
 ORDER BY Internship_StartDate1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly confusing `LIKE` wildcards with other comparisons.  `'%'` only works with `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE`.

More importantly, use date comparisons on dates!  This is quite important for optimization.  You should be writing your condition as:

```
select Internship_StartDate1
from [Media_BPM].[dbo].[BP_UGME]
where TrainingType = 'Medical Internship Training' and
      Internship_StartDate1 >= '2020-01-01' and
      Internship_StartDate1 < '2020-07-01'
order by Internship_StartDate1 desc;
```

There is no need to convert dates to string for such comparisons.  And the direct comparisons allow:

- Converting dates to strings incurs overhead on every row that is processed.
- The query optimizer to choose appropriate indexes, if available.
- The query optimizer to choose appropriate partitions, if available.
- The query optimizer to choose the appropriate algorithms, because sizing statistics are likely to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that I ended up using YYYYMMDD in my SQL code because this (seems to) always work(s) even without formatting, and believe me I have experienced troubles with MDY (MS default) vs. DMY (e.g. Germany) a lot. So, for the entire year 2020 I'd search like that:

```
select Internship_StartDate1 
  from Media_BPM.dbo.BP_UGME
 where TrainingType = 'Medical Internship Training' and
       --  first and last time tick in 2020
       Internship_StartDate1 between '20200101' and '20201231 23:59:59.997'
 order by Internship_StartDate1 desc
```